# Snapping to a stored relative rotation in y axis Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

This is for a Microsoft HoloLens application developed in Unity.

I am developing a feature that "saves" a viewpoint for the user to be able to go back to easily. I am doing this by storing the relative position/orientation of the objects in the scene to the main camera, and then restoring the objects to their previous relative position/orientation via voice command.

I have the position restoration working properly, and I only need to have the orientation in the yaw axis (y) be restored so that the user is forced to face the right way.

I attempted this solution for restoring the *relative* y orientation of the scene objects (in this case called "terrainContainer") to the main camera:

```
//this is the stored relative orientation in y
float deltaYaw = Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y; 

//this function adjusts the orientation of the terrainContainer to match previous relative orientation that was stored
public void SwitchRelativeOrientation(float deltaYaw, GameObject terrainContainer){
     float curDeltaYaw = Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
     float diffDeltas = curDeltaYaw - deltaYaw;
     float setYaw = terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + diffDeltas;
     setYaw = Utils.MathUtils.Normalise(setYaw, 0, 360); //normalises the value recovered to a range from [0,360]

     //adjusting terrainContainer rotation
     terrainContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(terrainContainer.transform.rotation.x, setYaw, terrainContainer.transform.rotation.z);
}
```

This implementation works when I do the following:

- Save my viewpoint
- Move the main camera around in both position and orientation (via head movement in HoloLens)
- Move the terrain in position, but NOT orientation
- Restore to the viewpoint

This implementation *fails* when I do the following:

- Save my viewpoint
- Reset the terrain's orientation to 0 degrees
- Rotate the terrain by an arbitrary amount in either direction
- Restore to the viewpoint

When the failure occurs, the orientation is off by how much the terrain was rotated. So if the terrain was rotated by 20 degrees counter clockwise by the user, and the terrain should be at 50 degrees, then the terrain ends up at 70 degrees.

I cannot figure out why this occurring. I do my rotation before the position change. I would appreciate any help you can offer!

EDIT:
As mentioned in a comment below I took a slightly different approach to solve this problem that ended up working:

```
//this is the stored relative orientation in y
float deltaYaw = viewpoint.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y

//this function adjusts the orientation of the terrainContainer to match previous relative orientation that was stored
public void SwitchRelativeOrientation(float deltaYaw, GameObject terrainContainer){
     Quaternion toQuat = Camera.main.transform.localRotation;
    //my implementation is flat on the xz plane
     toQuat.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, toQuater.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    //orient terrain to same as camera
    terrainContainer.transform.rotation = toQuat;
    //now add the previous difference in rotation to the terrain
    terrainContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + deltaYaw, terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment below I took a slightly different approach to solve this problem that ended up working:

```
//this is the stored relative orientation in y
float deltaYaw = viewpoint.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y

//this function adjusts the orientation of the terrainContainer to match previous relative orientation that was stored
public void SwitchRelativeOrientation(float deltaYaw, GameObject terrainContainer){
     Quaternion toQuat = Camera.main.transform.localRotation;
    //my implementation is flat on the xz plane
     toQuat.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, toQuater.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    //orient terrain to same as camera
    terrainContainer.transform.rotation = toQuat;
    //now add the previous difference in rotation to the terrain
    terrainContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + deltaYaw, terrainContainer.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But I can also se another problem

```
terrainContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(terrainContainer.transform.rotation.x, setYaw, terrainContainer.transform.rotation.z);
```

Rotation is a quaternion, which is essentially a Vector4, and you can address its members via rot.x, rot.y, rot.z, rot.w, but those are NOT the same as euler angles, those parts that make up a quaternion. Try yhid instead:

```
    terrainContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(terrainContainer.transform.eulerAngles.x, setYaw, terrainContainer.eulerAngles.z);
```

Also by doing

```
setYaw = Utils.MathUtils.Normalise(setYaw, 0, 360);
```

you are truncating information if your setYaw is greater than 360 (which it may well be in some situations).
You can simply remove this line as unity works just fine with angles greater than 360, or if you really need to have the value truncated you can do

```
setYaw = setYaw % 360; //modulo division
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions zambari! Those changes didn't fix my problem, but I found a better approach which I will post above in the edit.